# How can I test that a webapp is available to users in China?

Tags: testing, country-specific

Does anyone know what the best (quickest) way to test whether a small webapp is viewable inside China? We've already tested with a small but varied group but we're looking to extend our testing further.

Ideally I'd love to just have a couple of QA's inside China to open the page and see if it loads etc, screen recording the results.

We've been through the VPN into China route but as it stands they're all shut down.

Comment: I'm guessing you could probably find a non political Chinese forum online and recruit volunteers.  Many of them want to learn English and would love to help you.  It may not let you see the site, but it might give you users inside China,

Comment: Search for: "great firewall test" or something similar, you'll get some sites like [this one](http://www.chinafirewalltest.com/), that are designed for this very purpose.

Comment: Could this help you?
https://www.appinchina.co/services/localization/content-regulations/

Answer (score 1):

One option to test your webapp inside China would be to use a website testing service that has servers located in China. These services can help you verify if your website is accessible and performing well within China's Great Firewall. Some popular website testing services that offer China testing include Pingdom, WebPageTest, and Dotcom-Monitor.

Another option would be to collaborate with a Chinese-based QA testing company to assist with your testing needs. These companies have highly skilled and experienced testers who can help you test your webapp within China. You can also request screen recordings of the testing process for transparency and documentation purposes.

I hope this helps!